# No launcher after update to 3.5.0-27

Tags: 12.10, unity

New user to Ubuntu here:

Just installed the new updates for 3.5.0-27, after reboot, my screen changes to 1024x768 and I don't see any launcher at all.

Can't access any settings besides the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

I tried to purge uninstall and reinstall `nvidia-current`, but still no avail.

I've tried (`unity --reset-icons`) brings up nothing but error messages related to GLX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this bug affecting nvidia users:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1166765

temp fix is open a terminal    and execute the following:

$ gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
$ shutdown -r now

if this fixes it ... maybe not permanent yet so keep this note handy.

Answer (score -1):

+1 ... one of two monitors is dark and no unity launcher on the survivor.
       go back to 3.5.0-26 and everything is fine.

from Xorg log near the time of one of the failures ...

> [    18.624] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
>   [    18.624] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
>   [    18.624] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>   [    18.624]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    18.624]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
>   [    18.624] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
>   [    18.624] (II) Unloading nvidia
>   [    18.624] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 32538)
>   [    18.624] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
>   [    18.624] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
>   [    18.624] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    18.624]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.2
>   [    18.624]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
>   [    18.624]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
>   [    18.624] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
>   [    18.624] (II) Unloading nouveau
>   [    18.624] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 32538)
>   [    18.624] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
>   [    18.625] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
>   [    18.625] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
>   [    18.625] (II) Unloading nv
>   [    18.625] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)

Perhaps more revealing, from syslog around the same time ...

> Apr 15 20:39:12 hod kernel: [112066.363439] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 304.88, but
>   Apr 15 20:39:12 hod kernel: [112066.363439] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 304.84.  Please
>   Apr 15 20:39:12 hod kernel: [112066.363439] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
>   Apr 15 20:39:12 hod kernel: [112066.363439] NVRM: components have the same version.

google searches show this to be a common problem, but I saw no references to 
the current situation.   Is it as simple as old driver tripped a histocompatibility
interlock, and backed-off?  An attempt to update nvidia-current says it is up-to-date.

So do I just stay on 3.5.0-26 and hope that the nvidia driver gets updated soon?
Is there a more proactive solution to this problem?
Am I on crack?

Comment: Is this an answer? If so I can't see it. This is not a forum and you need to provide a clear answer. If its a question then follow [ask]